# Take a partial screenshot with command line in other screen

Tags: command-line, mac

This seems like a really easy fix but I have the following problem:

- I want to take a partial screen using the command line
- Therefore I do this

  screencapture -w -R8,104,1460,620 ~/Desktop/test4.png

This works, however I would like to operate the command line in another screen. Any thoughts on what I should add so i can operate the command line in one screen and take a partial screenshot in another one.

Answer (score 1):

`screencapture -w` is window mode, so you'd have to click in the correct window anyway, whichever screen it was on.

Removing the -w & adding the width of the first monitor [assuming they are set 1 left, 2 right] will capture the area on the 2nd screen.

so
`screencapture -R8,104,1460,620 ~/Desktop/test4.png`
will capture the top left of screen 1 &
`screencapture -R2568,104,1460,620 ~/Desktop/test4.png`
will capture the same area on screen 2, assuming a 2560 screen

Type `man screencapture` for more info